# To prove a property of a positive semidefinite matrix with the zero first entry.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite, block-matrices

I want to prove the following:

If the matrix
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
0&\vec{q}^T \\
\vec{q}&N
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is PSD, then $\vec{q}=\vec{0}$.

The only three properties of a positive semidefinite matrix that I know is the non-negative eigenvalues, $\vec{x}^TM\vec{x}\geq0$, and $\exists U$ such that $M=U^TU$, but I have no idea to apply them into this question. Any hints?

Comment: In the title it says "with the zero first entry". Where do I find  this zero first entry  in the problem description?

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, I just edited the description.

Comment: ... just to further clarify: $\vec{q}$ is a vector,   and the "center" elements of the matrix are zero - true?

Comment: @Andreas I don’t know what you mean by the “center” element. Only the first foremost entry is known zero, $\vec{q}$ is an unknown vector, and $N$ is an unknown submatrix.

Comment: Oh, $N$ is a matrix, I thought it were a number. This clarifies it.

Comment: @Andreas No, because if $\vec{q}=\vec{0}$, we can use the PSD of M and let $\vec{x}=(0,x_2, \dots, x_n)$ to prove that $N$ is also PSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This text uses that N is a PSD matrix (see comments)

Let $\vec y$ be the vector $\vec x$ without the first element.

By direct summation: 
$$\vec{x}^TM\vec{x} = 2 x_1 \sum_{i=2}^N  x_i q_i +    \vec y^T N \vec y
$$

Now for  $\vec q = \vec 0$ this is PSD. Conversely, if  $\vec q \ne \vec 0$, then you can always find a  $\vec x$ for which it is not PSD. If $q_2 \ne 0$ (otherwise choose any other nonzero element of $\vec q$), then choose $x_i = 0$ for $i=3 \cdots N$ and $x_1 \ne0$, $x_2 \ne 0$. This gives 
$\vec{x}^TM\vec{x} = 2 x_1 x_2 q_2 + (x_2, 0, \cdots  ,0)^TN(x_2, 0, \cdots  ,0)
$. Since N is  PSD, we have $(x_2, 0, \cdots  ,0)^TN(x_2, 0, \cdots  ,0) = R \ge 0$.

If $R=0$, you select  $x_1 = -x_2 q_2$ which makes the expression negative.
If $R>0$, you select  $x_1 = -x_2 q_2 R /(q_2^2 x_2^2)$ which also makes the expression negative.

So you can always construct cases for $\vec q \ne  \vec 0$ which violate the PSD condition.

So you need $\vec q = \vec 0$ to obtain PSD.

Comment: Thanks for your help! BTW, I said in the comment that $N$ is PSD if $\vec{q}=\vec{0}$, but I think that your method still works.

Comment: Using your comment, N is PSD in any case. You don't need $\vec q = \vec 0$ for your argument. With any $\vec q$, consider $\vec y^T N \vec y = (0,x_2, \dots, x_n)^T M (0,x_2, \dots, x_n)$. Now from the PSD condition for M, the RHS says that this is nonnegative, hence $\vec y^T N \vec y$ is nonnegative for any $\vec y$, hence N is PSD.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I mean that your method actually doesn’t need this property. Anyway, thanks a lot!